# Como posso forçar refresh após deploy?

Tags: php, deploy, atualização

Tenho uma aplicação web feita em PHP, e queria forçar que, sempre que fizesse deploy de uma nova versão da aplicação o cliente fosse "obrigado" a atualizar tudo que tivesse mudado, como imagens, CSS, JS, etc.

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Pede para o usuário apertar CTRL+SHIFT+R!

Comment: Utilize um parâmetro como versão com um `timestamp`. Ex: `https://www.example.com/images/icons.png?v=1519330900`

Comment: eu geralmente faço o que o Valdeir falou, mas estou trabalhando numa mudança que vou avisar pros clients conectados via socket que o site mudou e forçar o reload

Comment: Talvez configurar o Web server subjacente, e.g. usando o módulo mod_expires do Apache

Comment: Você pode versionar seu assets (CSS, JS, etc), usando ferramentas como o webpack. Ferramentas como essa, permitem entre outras coisas adicionar um número de versão ao final do nome original do arquivo como o Valdeir Psr disse. Assim o browser vai ignorar o cache do asset versionado anteriormente e carregar o mais novo.

Comment: Pergunta objetiva: Você está usando alguma ferramenta pra gerenciar os assets? É viável usar? Ou quer fazer isso num projeto onde você está usando as urls dos assets diretamente mesmo?

Comment: O melhor é mudar o nome dos assets. Criar uma versão na querystring só muda a confusão de lugar. Você pode trocar um `main.css?v=125` para `main.css?v=127` e de repente esqueceu de subir o verdadeiro `main.css` versão 127 - acabou de dar um tiro no pé, pq quando subir o verdadeiro 127, vai ter que mudar de novo a versão, pq o que tá cacheado como v=127 é o 125. Se mudar no nome do arquivo, tem a certeza de nao dar confusão nem no desenvolvimento nem no deploy.

Comment: "Ah, mas se eu mudar o nome vou ter que mexer nos sources". Mas é melhor mexer nos sources do que fingir que resolveu. De qq forma, você pode usar variáves e um config centralizado de nomes, assim nos sources você usa link rel="" src="$config_cssmain" e troca o $config_cssmain num arquivo centralizado ou manifest, assim tem um pouco mais de previsibilidade (e facilidade de dar um rollback emergencial só alterando a config se algum asset tiver problema no deploy)

Comment: @Bacco mas isso me trás um problema, que não sendo grave é chato. Em termos de repositório de versões, vais estar sempre a criar um novo ficheiro e nunca a alterar o anterior.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters não estou usando nenhuma ferramenta. Poderá ser viável usar se não implicar muito tempo/trabalho.

Comment: @JorgeB. de qualquer forma, um sistema de deploy supostamente deveria ter como remover coisas obsoletas, não? Tem muitas situações onde arquivos ficam desnecessários, ao se atualizar um framework ou mesmo folha de estilo.

Comment: @Bacco certo. Isso não é problema. O único "problema" é não haver registo de alterações no repositório.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em uma época remota, eu até criei uma [biblioteca](https://github.com/phplegends/assets) para poder gerenciar os meus scripts e folhas de estilo adicionadas ao site.

O ponto principal que me fez querer criar a biblioteca foi ter um parâmetro que eu definisse em um lugar e que afetaria todos os scripts, imagens e folhas de estilo que tivesse em meu site.

Meu objetivo não é fazer propaganda da biblioteca aqui (até porque eu acho que hoje em dia tentaria resolver de outras formas), mas pensando no caso onde você tem um site com seus scripts, imagens e folhas de estilo, sem utilização de ferramentas modernas como `gulp`, `webpack` e afins.

## Técnica 1: Forçando a atualização de todos os assets

Eu acho que você poderia criar uma função que receberia normalmente como parâmetro o nome do seu asset. E dentro dessa função, ele montaria o nome para seu `asset` baseando-se em alguma flag, que faria com que forçasse uma atualização em todos seus clientes.

Mais ou menos assim:

em algum lugar você define:

```
 define('APP_VERSION', '1.0.0');
```

Você cria uma pequena função.

```
 function asset($url) {
      return sprintf('%s?version=%s', $url, APP_VERSION);
 }
```

Aí, ao invés de declarar seus scripts e imagens assim:

```
 <img src="/img/futebol.jpg">
 <script src="/js/app.js">
```

Você declararia assim:

```
<img src="<?= asset('/img/futebol.jpg') ?>">
<script src="<?= asset('/js/app.js') ?>"></script>
```

Isso faria com que a url gerada acima fosse:

```
 /img/futebol.jpg?version=1.0.0
 /js/app.js?version=1.0.0
```

Aí, caso você fizesse alguma publicação de uma nova versão no sistema, você apenas trocaria sua constante `APP_VERSION`.

```
 define('APP_VERSION', '1.0.1')
```

Isso faria com que seus assets tivessem um `?version=1.0.1` adicionados, forçando, portanto, o navegador do cliente a pegar as informações novas do servidor.

**Vantagens do método acima**:

- Você altera em um lugar e tudo é atualizado.
- Não precisa alterar estrutura de pastas ou usar bibliotecas para fazer o trabalho

**Desvantagens**:

- Se você quiser apenas atualizar um arquivo, não seria possível, pois com a mudança da versão, todos os assets receberiam o acréscimo de um `?version=VERSÃO` diferente.
- Você tem que chamar uma função ao invés de simplesmente declarar o `src` ou `href` do seu asset diretamente

## Técnica 2: Forçando a atualização individual

A segunda técnica que eu tinha pensado visa atualizar cada asset individualmente. Mas, para fazer isso, **é necessário conhecer o caminho físico** do asset, através do PHP.

A ideia é a mesma da função acima, com uma pequena modificação:

```
  function asset($path)
  {

      // exemplo : 'c:\window\xampp\htdocs\project\assets/img/futebol.jpg'
      $fullpath = __DIR__ . '/assets/' . $path;

      return sprintf('%s?last_modified=%d', $path, filemtime($fullpath));
  }
```

No caso acima, a função `filemtime` é responsável por ler um arquivo no disco e informar, através de um unixtimestamp, a última data de modificação.

Ao fazer isso, você estaria gerando algo parecido com isso:

```
   /img/futebol.png?last_modified=1535132483
   /js/app.js?last_modified=1535632483
```

**Vantagens**

- Atualiza cada arquivo individualmente
- Não precisa de alterar nenhum valor manualmente. Se o arquivo for modificado, então sempre será atualizado no navegador

**Desvantagens**:

- Impossibilita a utilização de url absoluta na função, já que usamos parte  do path para construir o caminho físico do arquivo para obter a data de modificação.
- A cada asset adicionado, vai chamar a função `filemtime`. Algumas pessoas minimalistas gostariam de evitar tantas chamadas a essa função.

Mas ainda sim, é possível contornar o problema da opção 1, descrito nas desvantagens do segundo método. Basta verificar se o arquivo existe, para aplicar a verificação da data de modificação. Caso não exista, use a opção 1 apresentada!

Exemplo:

```
define('APP_VERSION', '1.0.1');

function asset($path)
{
    $fullpath = __DIR__ . '/assets/' . $path;

    // Se existir, coloca a data de modificação

    if (file_exists($fullpath)) {
        return sprintf('%s?last_modified=%d', $path, filemtime($fullpath));
    }

    return sprintf('%s?version=%d', $path, APP_VERSION);
}
```

Comment: Comentem aí, fiquei me perguntando se daria pra usar `#` ao invés de `?`. Daria certo??

Comment: Cara, sensacional! Só mudaria uma coisa, o `APP_VERSION` poderia vir de um arquivo estático, e no caso eu recomendaria um tipos de assets terem versões diferentes, mas todo o resto, incluindo o filemtime acho que resolve muito.

Answer (score 3):

A melhor maneira de fazer isso é utilizar um parâmetro único no link que force a atualização dos seus scripts. Exemplo, dentro da tag `head` da sua página carregue os scripts dessa maneira:

```
<script src="script.js?v=<?php echo $version; ?>"></script>
<link href="style.css?v=<?php echo $version; ?>" rel="stylesheet">
```

Sendo `$version` alguma string que consiga ser única em função de cada deploy. Eu normalmente coloco a versão do último deploy via Git.