# Refresh automático apenas uma vez em PHP

Tags: php, javascript, session, cookies, html-meta-tag

Preciso fazer um "refresh" automático em algumas páginas do site de um cliente. Porém, esse "refresh" precisa acontecer apenas **UMA** vez.

Eu sei que daria pra eu colocar a meta tag abaixo, por exemplo:

```
<meta content="3;url=http://www.meusite.com.br/index.php" http-equiv="Refresh" />
```

Mas ela atualizaria sempre a cada 3 segundos. E eu queria que atualizasse só uma vez. Como posso fazer isso? Com uso de SESSION, COOKIE ou alguma outra coisa?

Comment: Qual seria o motivo de fazer esses refresh? Talvez haja uma solução mais apropriada.

Comment: @Sam, também pensei nisso.

Comment: Relacionada: [Como posso forçar refresh após deploy?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/278209/7210)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, Gustavo.

Uma solução que vejo é utilizar parâmetros de URL junto com a função `time()` do PHP.

```
$show = false;

if (isset($_GET['t']) {
  $time = $_GET['t'];

  if (time() - $time > 5) {
    $show = true;
  }
} else {
  $show = true;
}

if ($show) {
  echo '<meta content="3;url=http://www.meusite.com.br/index.php?t=' . time() . '" http-equiv="Refresh" />';
}
```

Explicando o código:

1. Definido a variável `$show`, que indicará se é para ser inserido na página o comando de atualização depois de 3 segundos, inicialmente definida em `false` (não mostrar a menos que...);
2. Verificando a existência do parâmetro URL `t` que armazena o tempo em segundo do ultimo tempo que chamou o comando de atualização de página;

   1. Uma vez existindo, compara a diferença da ultima vez que chamou a função de atualização com o tempo atual;

      1. Se a diferença for maior que 5 segundos (considerando 3 segundos mais uma margem de erro de 2 segundos), é sinal de que esse tempo foi de uma requisição "antiga", o que valida uma nova atualização da página, considerando um usuário novo: `$show = true`.
   2. Não existindo o parâmetro URL `t`, caracteriza como um novo usuário portando é mostrado o comando de atualização de página `$show = true`.
3. Se `$show == true` exibe o comando de atualização de página, sendo enviado com o parâmetro `t = time()`, tempo corrente em segundos.

**Possível problema deste algoritmo:**
Se a página demorar mais que dois segundos para carregar, é possível que isso vá além da margem de erro do tempo (de dois segundos), o que será considerado sempre como um novo usuário, atualizando a toda requisição.

Answer (score -2):

$reload=$_GET["reload"];
if($reload==""){
<-SCRIPT->self location='&reload=sim';</-script->
}