# Como incluir um Refresh no window.open com _parent?

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho um formulário de textos e fotos que envia para grava.php

E no grava.php redireciona para resultado.php com:

```
<script>window.open("resultado.php?id="+<?=$id?>+"","_parent");</script>
```

pag resultado.php recebe o id e pega no BD a foto (nova ou alterada) e texto

```
<?php
ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html dir="ltr" lang="pt-BR">
<head>basico,css,viewport</head>
<body>
<?php
$id=(isset($_GET['id'])) ? (int)$_GET['id'] : 0 ;
if($id>0){
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/abre/conexao.php';
    $sel=mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,"select * FROM XXXX WHERE id=".$id." LIMIT 1"));
    $foto=$sel['foto'];$texto=$sel['texto'];
    mysqli_close($con);

    if($foto<>''){
        echo"<img src='xxxx/foto.jpg'>";
        }
    echo'<br><b>Texto</b><br>',$texto;
}
echo'</body></html>';
ob_end_flush();
```

**Problema**: Qdo o usuário **troca** de foto e grava, a pag resultado mostra a foto antiga.

É preciso atualizar a pag ou limpar cache. (mas a maioria não atualiza)

**Pergunta**: 
É possível incluir um refresh neste js ?

ou limpar o cache da pag. resultado.php?

Agradeço antecipadamente

Comment: Não use window.open. Use `location.href = "resultado.php";`.

Comment: Olá Sam, vc pode dar uma olhada no meu problema? Usei a sugestão do Taffarel e não resolveu. E parece que ele está ausente. Agradeço muito

Comment: você pode setar o name e a origin, passando uma string aleatória... 
`var strWindowFeatures = "menubar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes"; window.open("http://www.sua-url.com.br/", "nome_"+randUrl(), strWindowFeatures);` você não precisa definir como `_parent`...

Comment: Ivan, inclui no grava.asp mas não redireciona (fica tela branca) fiz assim: <script>var strWindowFeatures = "menubar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes";
window.open("https://site/dir1/pasta1/resultado.php?ir=2&id=2", "nome_"+randUrl(), strWindowFeatures);
</script>

Comment: Esse grava.php está dentro de um iframe?

Comment: Caro Geo não use `date()` ou `time()` para forçar o cache atualizar, isso simplesmente fará com que a cada acesso você tenha que repetir o download, o consumo de dados da pessoa será gasto sem necessidade, se usar `filemtime()` como sugeri em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/169846/3635 ele vai usar a data de modificação do proprio arquivo novo como parametro e o cache do navegador ainda poderá fazer proveito. Aqui eu explico com mais de detalhes: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/57048/3635. Lembre-se de colocar em todas páginas que contiverem essa imagem.

Comment: Relacionada: [Como posso forçar refresh após deploy?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/278209)

Comment: Usei o filemtime() conf. exemplo na questão 169846 e deu tudo certo. Agradeço a todos pela super aula e material didático. Desculpem-me pela duplicidade (antes de postar pesquisei por window.open)

Answer (score 1):

**Sim, é possível.**

> Tente este código:

```js
let myWindow = window;
myWindow.open("resultado.php","_parent");
myWindow.location.href="#";
```

> Mas há outras formas de se fazer isso.

Comment: Ficou em looping no grava.php (precisei abortar)

Comment: myWindow.location.href="#";

Comment: Não esta atualizando. Testei várias vezes. redireciona correto mas não atualiza

Comment: Se você puder, coloca o código do arquivo resultado.php.

Comment: Inclui na pergunta o resultado.php (com 1 foto/texto, pois se repetem até 10) e também mais algumas informações. Agradeço a atenção

Comment: Taffarel, conf.sua solicitação, coloquei o código do arquivo resultado.php. Alguma sugestão? Obrigado.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver o problema?

Comment: Ainda não. O Ivan (acima) deu uma sugestão que falta depurar (não redireciona)

Answer (score 0):

Adicione um timestamp no caminho da imagem que irá evitar o cache do navegador:

```
echo "<img src='xxxx/foto.jpg?". date("ymdHis") ."'>";
```

A função `date("ymdHis")` irá adicionar sempre um valor único a cada segundo após o `?` (ano, mês, dia, hora, minuto e segundo), fazendo com que o navegador sempre ache que é uma imagem diferente (ex.: `foto.jpg?191009191137`).